# Converting tensorflow tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm to tf2.0

Tags: tensorflow, layer

I would like to change the following code from tf1.0 to tf2.0

```
 tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm(
      inputs=input_tensor, begin_norm_axis=-1, begin_params_axis=-1, scope=name)
```

This code is taken from https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/modeling.py
Line 364.

Please help me.

Answer (score 6):

@rishabh-sahrawat's answer is right, but you should do something like this:

```
layer_norma = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis = -1)
layer_norma(input_tensor)
```

In the BERT case you linked, you should modify the code with something like this:

```
def layer_norm(input_tensor, name=None):
  """Run layer normalization on the last dimension of the tensor."""
  layer_norma = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis = -1)
  return layer_norma(input_tensor)
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LayerNormalization) is the equivalent way to do this in TF2.0

```
tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(input_tensor, axis = -1)
```